# Gnuplot: substract varying offset from multiple data files

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

After my last question was answered as well (thanks @ Christoph!), I have another one.

I have multiple data files I want to plot but at each file I want to substract in column 2 the first value so every data file starts at 0.

I have the following code:

```
file = 'file_1 file_2 file_3 ... filen'

intime(COL) = strptime("%H:%M:%S",strcol(COL))

do for [i=1:words(file)] {
        stats word(file,i) using (intime(2)):3 nooutput
        timemin(i) = STATS_min_x
}

plot for [i=1:words(file)] word(file,i) u (intime(2)-timemin(i)):3 notitle
```

The problem is that the variable timemin(i) only contains the value of the last file.

Does anybody know how I can save all the different values for file_1 to file_n?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a string which contains all the computed minima:

```
file = 'file_1 file_2 file_3 ... filen'
timemin = ''
intime(COL) = strptime("%H:%M:%S",strcol(COL))

do for [i=1:words(file)] {
        stats word(file,i) using (intime(2)):3 nooutput
        timemin = sprintf("%s %e", timemin, STATS_min_x)
}

plot for [i=1:words(file)] word(file,i) u (intime(2)-word(timemin, i)):3 notitle
```

Since you want to subtract the very first value, you could also use another method without `stats`:

```
file = 'file_1 file_2 file_3 ... filen'
intime(COL) = strptime("%H:%M:%S",strcol(COL))

ofs = 0
plot for [f in file] f using (ofs = ($0 == 0 ? intime(2) : ofs), intime(2) - ofs):3 notitle
```

This sets the variable `ofs` to the first value of column 2 in each data file (`$0` contains the row number). And note, that you can iterate over a word list with `in`.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried this, but I geht this error: `f_sprintf: attempt to print numeric value with string format`. So I changed `%s %e` to `%f`. Outside the for loop there is only the last value of `timemin` stored. So I have the same problem as bevore.

Comment: Yeah, know it is perfect! Thank you so much!