# How can I subtract the value in first row from all other values in the column?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to subtract all rows of a file from its first row, and then plot it. How can I implement such math work in gnuplot?
Here is an example of what i want to do:

[image]

Let's say i have a file that has two columns and 1000 rows. I want a script that subtract all data's in 2nd column from the 2nd column value in first row.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there are a similar questions on SO, however, apparently not so easy to find.
I would have searched for "normalization" or "offset".

The following example works even if you have single or double empty lines in your data. The expression in the plot command uses serial evaluation, check  `help operators binary`.

Sometimes, you might see similar solutions using the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`), however, which might lead to wrong results if you have empty lines in your data.

**Script:**

```
### offset data: subtraction of first value in a column
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 0   10
 1   11
 2   12
 3   13
 4   14
 5   15
 6   16
 7   17
EOD

plot t=0 $Data u 1:(t==0?y0=$2:0,t=t+1,$2-y0) w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Finally, after I spent more time for searching than writing this answer, I found a similar question where a time-offset was requested. However, the accepted solution is using the pseudocolumn 0, which might lead to wrong results if you have empty lines in your data. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26648969/7295599

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. I've tried to utilize your way in my script: `plot    t=0 "num/soil.velD.out" using 1:t==0?y0=$5:0,t=t+1,$5-y0)` but there's an error: ` "soilpwp" line 51: column() called from invalid context`, How can i fix it?

Comment: @AbolfazlNajafi you have a typo, missing opening paranthesis  `... using 1:(t==0.... `.